# Rails 3.2 Submitting has_many :through form Triggers Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Strange error and I've never come across this before.  If I'm submitting a many to many form,  it's triggering validation for one of the models in the has_many :through relationship.  When I take out the validations, the form submits ok.  Why are validations preventing a has_many :through form from submitting?  Here is the info

```
class Client
  has_many :client_routes
  has_many :routes, :through => :client_routes
  #plus many validations below
end

class Route
  has_many :client_routes
  has_many :clients, :through => :client_routes
end

class ClientRoute
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :route
```

in my form to create routes I have a ul div that I use for drag and drop with the following hidden field.  Those hidded fields are looped through an array of clients.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("route[client_ids][]", c.id) %>
```

I have several of validation rules in the Client class.  The form submits correctly when I comment out all of them.  I have added validations one by one to try to see which one trips it up, but all of the validations seem to give me the issue.

The validation error is as follows

```
1 error prohibited this route from being saved:
There were problems with the following fields
Clients is invalid
```

Here is the form where the partial is simply an empty ul for dragging and dropping:

```
<%= form_for Route.new, :remote => true do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>    <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :mileage %> <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :mileage %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :rate %>         <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :rate %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <div class="assign_clients">
    <%= render :partial => "client_routes" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is the create action of the controller

```
def create
  @route = Route.new(params[:route])
  if @route.save
    respond_with @route, :location => routes_url
  else
    flash[:notice]= "Not saved due to your incompetence"
  end
end
```

Another test that kinda works is that I added the following which skips validation,  but this result now skips validations that I have for the Route model.

```
if @route.save(:validation => false)
```

Comment: Can you post the form please?

Comment: @Zajn I added the info you requested

Comment: How are you adding `Client`s to a new `Route`? It's obvious that your form is failing the `Client` that is associated with the new `Route` isn't meeting its validations. The `Route` object won't save if its associated object aren't valid as well. Can you elaborate on how a `Client` is added to a `Route`?

Comment: The point is the form should never call the Client validations.  I'm simply adding client_id's to a lookup table called client_routes. When rails detects the hidden field in the above convention,  It automatically saves the client_ids and associated route_id to that table.  I am using drag and drop to populate the empty ul element with clients and that array is submitted with the form.

Comment: @Zajn I understand what you mean now.  I had a few records in the database that were created before I added the validations to the CLient model.  I had assumed that validations were only used when a record was created on that model.  Put that in an answer as I don't believe many people realize this behavior

Comment: Sure you don't want to put it in an answer and get the credit??